# Check if files exists in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if some files exist in a directory. If yes, I want to skip over those files and not perform any procedure. If no, then I want to perform some procedure.

Let say in directory `/setup/server` I have the following files:

```
systems-server01
systems-server02
system-server03
system-server04
```

If I run the command `./add-system.sh system-server05` my code should execute the readline procedure and add a new server.

But if I run the command `./add-system.sh system-server04` my code should echo "Server already exists, please enter a new server".

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
DOMAIN=my.home.fs.cville.com
if [ $# -lt 1]; then
   echo "Please enter filename\n"
   exit
fi

#I think this is where I need to do the check if files exist but I have 
#problem figure out how to do it

while read line ; do
    alt=(${line[@]}
    hostname=${alt[0]}
    ipaddress=${$alt[1]}
    mac=${alt[2]}
    iface=${alt[3]}
    profile=${alt[4]}

    copper system add --cobber --name=$hostname --profile=$profile --ip- 
    address=$ipaddress \ --interface=$iface --mac=$mac 
    --hostname=$hostname --dns-name=${hostname}.$DOMAIN
done<$1
copper sync
```

Comment: Run your script through https://shellcheck.net/. You've got a number of immediate syntax errors.

Comment: The `read` -> `line` -> `alt` bit is weird (unless there's a reason for that extra complexity), especially since it treats `line` like an array when it isn't. Why not just use `while read hostname ipaddress mac iface profile; do`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes where your comment block is, you can add a check like:

```
if [ -e /setup/server/"$1" ]; then
    echo "file exists, nothing to do"
    exit
fi
```

See 'help test' for the various tests available. '[' is synonymous to 'test'